# Windows Batch to display matched contents

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am facing issue in writing the matched file name ignoring first 7 characters in folders

```
@echo off
for %%i in ( "C:\*" ) do if exist "C:\temp\%%~nxi" (

  REM Set FileExistsName
  set "FileExistsName=%%~nxi"

  REM Set Skip 7 first characteres
  set "FileMatched=!FileExistsName:~7!"

  if "%FileMatched%" NEQ [] (
echo !FileMatched! >> C:\temp\fileoutput.txt
)

)

echo Script Completed
pause
exit
```

The script works as expected however it's not displaying matched output. Could someone advise.

Answer (score 0):

```
if "%FileMatched%" NEQ [] (
```

This will never be true (due to several reasons).

Probably you want to use

```
if "!FileMatched!" NEQ "" (
```